# Как серверу обработать и принять JSON запрос от vk

Tags: php

Немного глупый вопрос... но как принять запрос от vk  в формате json следующего типа

```
{"type":"confirmation","group_id":000000000}
```

Как php поймать этот POST запрос в формате JSON?

Comment: а что в переменной $_POST приходит?

Comment: Дословно: "Для получения уведомлений нужно подтвердить адрес сервера. На него будет отправлен POST-запрос, содержащий JSON:" собственно и все. и ниже строка которая в вопросе. я поэтому и не могу понять как принять то...

Comment: @Bookin, как посмотреть что приходит в POST без имени? Я с php плохо знаком к сожалению(

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю вы пробуете работать с [Callback Api](https://vk.com/dev/callback_api), там же, на странице, внизу, есть пример на php

```
...
//Получаем и декодируем уведомление 
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); 

//Проверяем, что находится в поле "type" 
switch ($data->type) { 
  //Если это уведомление для подтверждения адреса сервера... 
  case 'confirmation': 
    //...отправляем строку для подтверждения адреса 
    echo $confirmation_token; 
    break;  
...
```

Comment: Спасибо, я просто не понял как принять запрос без имени)